# codeigniter mysql column unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have declared the variable `upload_source` in SELECT but get error

**Unknown column 'upload_source' in 'where clause'**

```
   SELECT b.name as name, filename, upload_date, IF(filename LIKE '%.png%', 1, 0) as type, IF(ex_link!='', 0, 1) as upload_source, title, a.id
    FROM (`all_media` a)
    LEFT JOIN `admins` b ON `b`.`id`=`user_id`
    WHERE `a`.`approved` =  0
    AND `upload_source` =  0
    ORDER BY `filename` DESC
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot use** aliased expression/column in where clause. Use the same expression (which you defined in the `Select` clause), in the `Where` clause.

From [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
>   different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses to refer to the column.
>
> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

Do the following instead (I have improvised the `upload_source = 0` to `ex_link != ''`):

```
 SELECT b.name as name, 
        filename, 
        upload_date, 
        IF(filename LIKE '%.png%', 1, 0) as type, 
        IF(ex_link!='', 0, 1) as upload_source, 
        title, 
        a.id
 FROM `all_media` AS a 
 LEFT JOIN `admins` b ON `b`.`id`=`user_id`
 WHERE `a`.`approved` =  0
   AND ex_link != '' 
 ORDER BY `filename` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL the **WHERE** keyword could not be used with **aggregate functions**.
Try this with **Having Clause**:

`SELECT b.name as name, filename, upload_date, 
IF(filename LIKE '%.png%', 1, 0) as type, IF(ex_link!='', 0, 1) as upload_source,title, a.id
FROM (`all_media`a)
LEFT JOIN`admins`b ON`b`.`id`=`user_id
`WHERE`a`.`approved`=  0
HAVING`upload_source`=  0
ORDER BY`filename`DESC`